# The mean and the standard deviation of the values in its array parameter

Tags: java, jcreator

Here's My Code; and I can find an array with this and I would like to calculate the mean of the values (overall) after this I would like to calculate standard deviation of this but I couldn't understand the question exactly so I dont have a method for now. Here's the question for standard deviation (Write a method that takes two parameters --a set of int values in an array and a double value representing their mean-- and computes and returns the standard deviation of the values using the given mean.)

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{ 
    final static int N = 100;
    static int limit = 0;
    static int[] list;
    static int i, j;
    static int sum = 0;
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

 public static int[] generateArray ()
 {

    System.out.print ("Enter your array limit: ");
    limit = scan.nextInt();

    list = new int[limit];

    for(i = 0; i < limit; i++)
    {
        list[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 2 * N - N);
    }
    return list;
 }

 public static void printArray() 
 {      
    for(j = 0; j < limit; j++)
        System.out.print (list[j] + "\t");
 }

 public static void meanArray()
 {
    sum = sum + list[j];           //PROBLEM HERE
    System.out.println (sum);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {      
     generateArray();
     printArray();
     meanArray();                  //PROBLEM HERE
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate the mean value, add up all values in your list and devide them by the number of values:

```
public static void meanArray() {
    double result = 0;
    for(int i : list) {
        result += i;
    }
    result /= list.length;
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: I added that part into my code and changed values with my values however it gave 2 different errors. Unexpected return type and cannot find symbol. Did you realize that I am taking all values static at the beginning? Can you try your code with mine together please to solve the errors?

Comment: Unexpected return type probably occured because I accidently returned the value instead of printed it. I've edited my answer. Please try this again, if it doesn't work, post your Error Message along with the line in which it occurs.

Comment: There is a problem about list.size(). It is giving"cannot find symbol" error and the line of list.size();

Comment: Oops, I assumed your `list` field is a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) because you named it `list`, but it actually is an array. To get the length of an array, use `myArray.length`. So in your case, `list.length`. Pease consider renaming your array to something else than `list` because it is not a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Comment: Can't be, I've just tested my code and it works. Please revalidate that you are using `list.length`. If it still doesn't work, post your code.

Comment: OK my friend my fault. I was writing list.length(). Problem was paranthesis. It's working now. Thank you :)